# Updating CentOS

Tags: yum, centos5, update

I have a CentOS 5.5 installation with ruby, dovecot (and some other soft) installed from source, and soft like postfix, samba, bind etc. installed from yum repositories.
This box is online for more than six months.
Now, if I do a `yum update` I see that there will be updated the kernel, bind, postfix and a bunch of other packages.

If I run the update:

1. Will I have to install again the software previously installed from source because of the kernel update?
2. Will I have to configure again the software installed from repositories (like postfix, samba etc.) beause of the updates, or the configuration is kept during the update process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Only kernel modules you installed yourself.
2. Look for files that end in ".rpmnew" and ".rpmsave". Those are likely to be configuration files which you can inspect to see which changes are necessary.

And as always, perform this on a testing machine before applying it to production.

Comment: In other words, I will have to reinstall the software installed from source because of the kernel update, and I will have to reconfigure the updated modules (in a way or other)?

Comment: You will have to reinstall kernel modules you installed yourself. Neither ruby nor dovecot is a kernel module. Package updates *may* have configuration file updates, but you will be able to tell which.

Comment: Where do I look for ".rpmnew" and ".rpmsave" files?

Comment: Wherever configuration files are found. Their presence will be announced if you use yum at the command line.